# Best practices for restricting access to enum parameter in C#

Tags: c#, .net, enums, coding-style

Consider for the question this [`String.Split` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which takes a [`StringSplitOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enum as a parameter.

Isn't it bad that the enum itself is public and accessible to everything that includes the System namespace? I mean, the enum is completely specific to options of the `Split` method, yet it's available outside of it's scope.

Perhaps there is a better way to model this, like putting the enum inside the String class itself, and accessing it by using `String.SplitOptions` for instance? I very rarely see this (I actually can't remember any such case now), so I assume it is not preferred for some reason. In general, I think reducing the scope of things is a best practice because you lower the chance of problems occurring by using a class/member in an incorrect scope, so to speak.

I'm using `Split` as an example here, but it is quite common for a `Enum` to be used only by a method or class in our code base too. I generally create the enum as a public type in a separate cs file like any other class, but I would love to hear other approaches to this 'problem'.

**Update:**

I just found [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/10/24/484120.aspx) that attacks this exact problem, with a `Folder` class and a `Filter` enum but again seems go against what I believe would be more correct in that case (placing the enum inside the class somehow). One of the comments in there from ToddM (which I happen to agree with) states:

> ...
>
> But, even then, I feel your logic is wrong. Your main complaint
>   against embedding the enum inside of the class is that it will take
>   too long to type. Given how verbose C# tends to be, this is not really
>   a sensible argument. In VS, CTRL+SPACE is your friend.
>
> Logically, I feel placing the enum inside of the class is far more
>   correct. Take your example: what is a MyNameSpace.Filter? Where does
>   it apply? I guess it's a filter for your namespace? It's impossible to
>   tell, especially if your namespace grows to contain dozens of classes.
>
> Now consider MyNameSpace.Folder.Filter -- it is, in my mind, far more
>   intuitive that Filter applies in some way, shape, or form to the
>   Folder class. Indeed, another class can be added to the namespace with
>   its own concept of filter, one of whose members may be 'File'. Just
>   because you've introduced a new class into the namespace doesn't give
>   you the right to pollute that namespace with various 'helper' types.
>   If you are developing as part of a large development team, your style
>   is, well, rude.
>
> ...

Comment: If you put the enum inside the class scope it can still be used else where. If you make it private to the class, you will not be able to use it as parameter for a method on your class.

Comment: I have liked nested types like this. It doesn't overpopulate your intellisense, and also gives a better meaning. But not many inside MS are fond of it...

Comment: An argument against the article linked from your updated question: for readability purposes I would not like to see 'Folder.BlaBla(Folder.Filter.Bla)' but rather 'Folder.BlaBla(Filter.Bla)'. The only bad thing is that it pollutes the intellisense. But that only happens when there are other things with 'Filter' in it; the chance is slim that that will ever happen.

Comment: Regarding to your update - I think `Filter` is simply not very self-descriptive name for enum. That's why `MyNameSpace.Filter` looks non-intuitive. `Filter` is a very basic word, like `Service`, `Data` or `Manager` which I'd try to avoid. Name it `MyNameSpace.FolderFilter` and it will be easy to use and find.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky yes, I think `Filter` would be a good name only if the enum was nested to begin with, otherwise it would probably be better to call it `FolderFilter` as you say.

Answer (score 8):

It's an interesting idea to nest the `enum` in order to suggest that it has a reduced scope, or to give it better semantics. I have used this idea before in order to have both error codes and warning codes in a post-compiler [I developed](https://code.google.com/p/nroles/). This way, I could use the same enum name `Code` nested either in the [`Error` class](https://code.google.com/p/nroles/source/browse/src/NRoles.Engine/Messages/Error.cs) or the [`Warning` class](https://code.google.com/p/nroles/source/browse/src/NRoles.Engine/Messages/Warning.cs).

On the other hand, public nested types are generally discouraged. They can be confusing to clients who have to qualify them with the outer class name. Look at the related guidelines [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229027(v=vs.110).aspx). Some that are relevant:

> DO NOT use public nested types as a logical grouping construct; use namespaces for this.
>
> AVOID publicly exposed nested types. The only exception to this is if variables of the nested type need to be declared only in rare scenarios such as subclassing or other advanced customization scenarios.
>
> DO NOT use nested types if the type is likely to be referenced outside of the containing type.
>
> For example, an enum passed to a method defined on a class should not be defined as a nested type in the class.

I believe those guidelines were followed when developing the `StringSplitOptions` enum, and most of the others in the BCL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the actual MSDN guideline quote. I think I've never seen this particular one, probably skimmed past it or something.

Answer (score 0):

`String.Split()` is public, so `StringSplitOptions` has to be public too. Both `String` and `StringSplitOptions` exist in the `System` namespace. Both have public scope. Neither is "available outside of [the other's] scope".

Comment: I meant outside of the scope of the `String` class itself, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the reasons is that it would make every call using an embedded enum wider (the name of the class becomes a mandatory prefix).

I personally wouln't appreciate having to use `ResultSetTransformer.ResultSetTransformerOptions` every time I have to use this enum, it would make my line horribly long.

But as others pointed out, I don't think it's standard in the framework to embed enums in classes at all, possibly for this reason.

Comment: What about `ResultSetTransformer.Options` instead? Also, why would the alias cause problems in that case? Wouldn't you be able to access the enum by the alias too?

Comment: You're right about ResultSetTransformer.Options, I just couldn't think of a better example right now, but the point is if you have a wide class name, you would have to use it in your call and it would take more place.

You're also right about the alias of string, I will remove it as this argument is very weak (it would be inconsistent to use lowercase string with uppercase string, but it's perfectly possible in other cases...)